# Call function within closure with string in variable

Tags: javascript

I know this question has been asked several times on SO but I combed through about 12 questions and none have been able to help me out.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
  var Joe = function(){
    function introduce(petname){
      alert(petname)
    }

     return {
    introduce:introduce
    }
   }();

  var Jane = function(){
   function introduce(petname){
      console.log(petname)
    }

     return {
    introduce:introduce
    }


  }()
 }
```

if I have the word joe stored in a variable how can I call the function

```
 Joe.introduce('pluto')
```

assuming I have the word Joe stored in a variable fnc

```
  fnc = "Joe";
```

I don't want to use eval. I have tried `window[fnc.introduce('pluto')]()`
as others have suggested but it does not work.

Comment: I'm confused, what does fnc  = "Joe" have to do with calling the inner function?

Comment: Take a look at a beginner's tutorial, and you'll learn how to create objects.

Comment: It would be a good idea to **NEVER** rely on variables names. (they are subject to minification)

Comment: `I have tried` - seeing as `Joe.introduce('pluto')` doesn't work, there's no surprise that you can't get anything else to work ... firstly you need to get `Joe.introduce('pluto')` working before you can proceed to get the "indirect" method working - which would not be easy (ignore previous method) - another point is, that Joe and Jane functions are only "visible" inside the `$(document).ready(function() { .. });` scope

Comment: @squint I'm no trying to create objects here. I have updated my question. I'm using module pattern with closures.

Comment: Oh, your fixed code makes more sense. Using variables like this isn't great. Objects work much better for dynamic access.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think to do this is something like this...

Store your functions in an object, then reference the function with `object[fnc]`.

***edit:*** updated original code to reflect OP's edits

```js
fnc = 'Joe';

$(document).ready(function () {
  var object = {
    Joe: function () {
      function introduce(petname) {
        alert(petname)
      }
      
      return {
        introduce: introduce
      };
    },

    Jane: function () {
      function introduce(petname) {
        console.log(petname)
      }
      
      return {
        introduce: introduce
      };
    },
  };
  
  object[fnc]().introduce('pluto');
  
  object['Jane']().introduce('goofy');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @zerkms unnecessary for this, I know, but OP is using `$(document).ready()` in their code which is jQuery.

Comment: It's important for reproducing the issue because it's that extra layer that's stopping his variables from being attached to the global `window`

Answer (score 0):

Try this! =)

```js
var Joe = function(){
  this.introduce = function(pet){
    alert(pet);
  }
}

var Jane = {
  introduce : function(pet){
    alert(pet);
  }
}

$(function(){
  new Joe().introduce('pluto');
  
  Jane.introduce('food');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: but what about `fnc = "Joe"`?

Comment: The "joe" function requires the use of "new" because the entire function may be loaded into a variable for it to work independently of the program.

Comment: this does not answer my question. the function Joe.introduce('pluto') should be invoked by just the variable fnc alone

Comment: if the translator of google not draw me in deception, it could go something like this?
**var fnc = "introduce"; 
Jane[fnc]('pluto');**

Comment: @Pinguto see the question again - `fnc = "Joe";`